# When i drag and drop a node with GMFappilication nothing is comes

Tags: eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

When i drag and drop a node with GMF application nothing is drawn and i have this exception 
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: While executing the operation, an exception occurred
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.DefaultOperationHistory.execute(DefaultOperationHistory.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramCommandStack.execute(DiagramCommandStack.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramCommandStack.execute(DiagramCommandStack.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui.parts.DiagramCommandStack.execute(DiagramCommandStack.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.gef.tools.AbstractTool.executeCommand(AbstractTool.java:425)
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that exception occurred during the command execution. Command is usually executed at the drop time. There should be a nested cause exception in your stack trace i think and it'd be interesting to see what that exception is.
In any case you should debug it and see what kind of command is being executed at the drop and see what exactly throws the exception.